# How can I send a ref int value to sqlserver from ASPx page?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, data-access-layer

I have this Stored procedure that returns UserID:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetUserID
(
@TopicID int, 
    @AskerID int
)
AS
SELECT       @AskerID = Post.Pt_CreatedBy 
WHERE        (Topic.Tp_ID = @TopicID)
RETURN @AskerID
```

Now when I call it from the Data access layer page using C#, I use this function:

```
 MyDatabaseDataContext StudyAppdb = new MyDatabaseDataContext();

public int GetUserID(int TopicID)
    {
        int UserID = -1;
        UserID = db.GetUserID(TopicID, UserID);
        return UserID;
    }
```

But GetUserID is supposed to take (int , ref int).... I don't know what is ref int & how can I pass it to the function.

Comment: Just declaring the sql database to access its functions.

Answer (score 4):

Since `GetUserID` is supposed to take `(int , ref int)`, you should also use the `ref` keyword explicily when calling this method. Instead of calling the method with `db.GetUserID(TopicID, UserID)` you should use the `ref` key word, something like:

```
public int GetUserID(int TopicID)
{
    int UserID = -1;
    UserID = db.GetUserID(TopicID, ref UserID);
    return UserID;
}
```

You can read more about [`ref` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can Write a Function Instead of Stored Procedure like given below

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetUserID
(
@TopicID int, 
    @AskerID int
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT       @AskerID = Post.Pt_CreatedBy 
WHERE        (Topic.Tp_ID = @TopicID)
RETURN @AskerID
END
```

OR change the procedure with OUTPUT parameter. Then You have to change the data access layer code to capture that value..